# Regexp - words apart?

Tags: regex

Regexp question:
Can one match if two words appear at the same time on a single line - but not if they
are more than say three words apart?

Example:
match and apart
should match in
 "my attempts to match words apart are not successful"
and
 "my attempts to match two words apart are not successful"
but not in
 "my attempts to match three or more words apart are not successful"

Thanks.

Comment: if it has really helped u..u should accept the `ans` which solved your problem or at least try to up vote others efforts that helped u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
match\s+(\S+\s){,2}apart
```

`\s` is a whitespace character and `\S` is a non-whitespace character. For the single line aspect, you might want to change `\s` to `[^\S\n\r]` as `\s` does also contain the line break characters `\n` and `\r`.

Answer (score 2):

Each word can be defined by something like `\w+\s`.

No more than three words can be written as `(\w+\s){0,3}`

So your regex could look like

```
/match\s(\w+\s){0,3}apart/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Although this depends on how you define words. Say, you would only consider letters to be words, and all non-letters to be separators:

```
firstword[^a-zA-Z\r\n]+(?:[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z\r\n]+){0,2}secondword
```

`[a-zA-Z]` is any letter character. `[^a-zA-Z\s]` any non-letter, non-linebreak character. That is pretty much all there is to it.